# Elastic search does have callback rails

Tags: elasticsearch

What is my intention is,
When I do a bulk update to elastic search, I want to know when and whether it is finished successfully.
This is required when I am writing following **rails test case**:

`1. Make 100(out of 1000) items featured in my product index
 2. Get all items back
 3. Check the items are sorted and 100 featured item is on top`

After I update items to ES in step 1, I like to know whether it is finished before getting all items back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a refresh after step 1. When the refresh completes, you know all the data you sent so far is indexed and ready for search.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html